# MySQL UNION SELECT and IN clause

Tags: mysql, select, union

I have two very simple table: `t1` and `t2` with the following rows:

table `t1`:

```
id, name
1   PBN
```

table `t2`:

```
id, name
100 FIBERHOME
```

Query 1:

```
SELECT name FROM t1 UNION SELECT name FROM t2 WHERE id IN (1)
```

Result is: PBN

Query 2:

```
SELECT name FROM t1 UNION SELECT name FROM t2 WHERE id IN (100)
```

Result is: PBN, FIBERHOME

But the expected result is: FIBERHOME..! What is the reason?

Comment: Strange! How do you expect only FIBERHOME, where you intentionally Select the name from t1?

Comment: I thought that the WHERE clause is global ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To expand on @Knep's answer, if you only want one `WHERE id IN ()`:

```
SELECT name FROM (
    SELECT id, name FROM t1
    UNION
    SELECT id, name FROM t2
) unioned
WHERE id IN (1,100)
```

Probably not great speed wise, so best to test.

Note also the `id` needs to be in the sub query to be used in the outer `WHERE`.

> I thought that the WHERE clause is global – @szpal

To answer the question as to why the WHERE isn't used for all queries in the UNION, think about two queries that don't share a column.

On their own:

```
SELECT id, name FROM x WHERE colA = 123
```

And:

```
SELECT id, name FROM y WHERE colB = 456
```

Then together with (the incorrect) single WHERE clause:

```
SELECT id, name FROM x
UNION
SELECT id, name FROM y
WHERE colB = 456 -- But table x doesn't have a colB!
```

Whereas if (correctly) the WHERE clause sits with each query:

```
SELECT id, name FROM x
WHERE colA = 123 -- I have a colA, still don't have a colB
UNION
SELECT id, name FROM y
WHERE colB = 456 -- I have a colB, still don't have a colA
```

Everyone's a winner!

Answer (score 2):

UNION sum up the two results.
In the first query, there is no condition so it returns **PBN**, then it adds the result of the second result **FIBERHOME**.
Using UNION you could try:

```
SELECT name FROM t1 WHERE id IN (100) UNION SELECT name FROM t2 WHERE id IN (100)
```

Answer (score 0):

The where condition in second query  will be executed before union.

```
SELECT name FROM t1
```

will return

```
id  name
1   PBN

SELECT name FROM t2 WHERE id IN (100)
```

will return

```
id    name
null  null
```

The union will combine above two results as

```
SELECT name FROM t1 UNION SELECT name FROM t2 WHERE id IN (100)

id  name
1   PBN
```

You can solve this by

```
SELECT 
name
FROM
    (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        interns_test_db.t1 UNION SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        interns_test_db.t2) A
WHERE
    ID IN (100)
```

But this may reduce the performance.